# Linq select array items based on sub class property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that looks like

```
public class ProductCategory {
  public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
  public string ProductCategoryName { get; set; }
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

and product has a few properties such as name, price etc.

I want a linq query that will return this structure of a product category with the array of products but only where a property of the product is equal to a value. For example where the price is 10.

I have tried

```
productCategory.SelectMany(p => p.Products).Where(x => x.Price == 10)
```

but this returns me an array of products but I want the product category with all the products that match the criteria.

As an extra challenge, I have multiple criteria as well, so in this example say prices are equal to 10, 30 or 50. There's an added complexity that one of the criteria has two values. I was going to do this just by calling the different selection criteria and then concatenate them at the end

```
var equalToTen = productCategory.Select... x.Price == 10
var equalToThirty = productCategory.Select... x.Price == 30
var equalToFiftyANdNameIsTest = productCategory.Select... x.Price == 50 && x.Name == "Test"

return equalToTen.Union(equalToThirty).Union(equalToFiftyANdNameIsTest)
```

but I'm sure that it can be done in a single statement without the need to concatenate at the end.

**Update**

The ProductCaegory isn't a single one either. It is the result of a EF query to the database. So it'll need to return multiple ProductCategories where the sub class Product query matches.

Comment: The problem here is that you want `ProductCategory`s as a result of your query but with a subset of elements in their `Products` property. This means that you either have to manipulate existing `ProductCategory` objects or create new ones.

Comment: @Dominik yes indeed, and as a LINQ query is not supposed to have side effects, we should not manipulate the originals

Answer (score 2):

So you want the product categories with prices that are in some list, and only those prices?

```
var prices = new[]{10,30};
categories.Select(c => new ProductCategory {
  ProductCategoryId = c.ProductCategoryId,
  ProductCategoryName = c.ProductCategoryName,
  Products = c.Products.Where(p => prices.Any(pp => pp == p.Price) || (p.Price == 50 && p.Name == "Test")).ToList()
}).Where(p => p.Products.Count > 0);
```

This projects the categories to new cats with filtered products. Only products with the relevant price `(10 or 30) (or 50 and called test)` make the cut.. and then only categories that still have products are returned

The criteria line could be expressed as

```
Products = c.Products.Where(p => p.Price == 10 || p.Price == 30 || (p.Price == 50 && p.Name == "Test")).ToList()
```

Which might be easier to read; I originally had 3 items in the array, but I'll leave the array form in as a demo of a typical `WHERE price IN (10,30,50)` in LINQ - we sort of approach it from the other angle and ask "for these prices 10, 30, 50 is any of them equal to the p.Price" rather than "is p.Price in [10,30,50]". Other forms of simplification are possible such as `.Where(p => prices.Contains(p.Price) ...` but I tend to fall back to the Any route because it allows more complex constructs

Comment: this looks good. I have my my problem though is that the original ProductCategory and Products are mapped entities to table and so I get an error that: 
"The entity or complex type 'ProductOption' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: If What is a ProductOption? In any case, just remove the `ProductCategory` (or Option: did you edit your class names for the purposes of the question?) from after the `new` to project to an anonymous type instead. It'll still work the same for most purposes and if you really need it as a ProductCategory you can map it back later